# handeling cookies and headers with agilitypack C#

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

agilitypack does excellent job for me in html parsing,
but what about other html aspects?
the object agilitypack.HtmlWeb allow access to cookies and headers?

Answer (score 5):

Access to the cookies and headers could be obtained through `HtmlWeb.PreRequest` and `HtmlWeb.PostResponse` handlers. The first one occurs before an HTTP request is executed. The second one occurs after an HTTP request has been executed. To use cookies you should enable it for an `HtmlWeb` instance by setting `HtmlWeb.UseCookies` property to `true`.

Here is an example:

```
var web = new HtmlWeb { UseCookies = true };
web.PreRequest += request =>
{
    // gets access to the cookie container
    var cookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;
    //  gets access to the request headers
    var headers = request.Headers;
    return true;
};
web.PostResponse += (request, response) =>
{
    // response headers
    var headers = response.Headers;
    // cookies
    var cookies = response.Cookies;
};
```